# How to perform justify for anchor tags in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styles

I added text-align:justify in the body tag,

```
body {
  text-align:justify;
}
```

All of the text got justified except the anchor links.

[image]

Can someone suggest to me the class that will justify the anchors as well?

Comment: please provide your code...

Comment: for text in a single line( being the last one ) , you can also use text-align-last:justify;

Comment: @Vpuram you have to add Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

to trigger justify on a single line(which happens to be also the last), you can use [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last)

> The `text-align-last` CSS property describes how the last line of a block or a line, right before a forced line break, is aligned.

```
body {
  text-align:justify;
  text-align-last:justify;
}
```

```css
p, a {
  max-width:500px;
  text-align:justify;
  text-align-last:justify;
  
}
a {
  color:red;
  background:yellow;
}
body>a {
display:block;

}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, <a>accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</a></p>
<hr/>
<a>accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</a>
```

Not yet supported everywhere  https://caniuse.com/css-text-align-last/embed/

Comment: Yep. You may want to emphasize more that it affects the links just because the links happen to be in each last line of their parents.not because they are different elements.